# How to remove only one fragment from backstack in Jetpack navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

I have back stack like: A -> B -> C -> D.
Now, I open B again.
I want to remove B from stack or make it top of stack.

Try to call popBackStack, but it make B/C/D remove from back stack.
Can you help me? Bro.It make me really crazy!